# Elements not appearing in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

Would really appreciate if anyone could take a look at my site and let me know why the elements on my landing page don't show up in Internet Explorer.

Everything works fine in Firefox, Safari and Chrome at least, but nothing appears at all in IE. I think the elements are there they are just invisible as if the mouse hovers over where the button or input box should be, the cursor changes.

I've tried cancelling out various parts of the HTML and CSS to see if anything triggers it to come back in, but to no avail so I'm truly stumped.

Really appreciate any help.

http://fitmumscoaching.co.uk/landing

Cheers,
Pinchy

Comment: you should put the code that does not work in IE here in the question.

Comment: In which version of IE are you testing?

Comment: I've just tried in IE 11 and it all just works.

Comment: There'd be a lot of code to put in so I thought it may be simpler to put a link to the page and then you can browse the code from there. @Baklap4 I'm testing on IE8...! Is there any general kind of guide for what elements are less compatible with older versions of IE that I can try to address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in IE 7, IE 8  but not in IE 9.

In style.css line number 925 instead of `opacity: 0` make it `1`. It will be displayed in IE9 also.

Or you can simply remove opacity from below.

```css
#banner, #banner2 .inner {opacity:1;}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks SO much! Seems I've incurred a hell of a load of downvotes for this! Not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see:

It works in IE 11 and IE 10.

I think you should make your site IE 9 and less compatible.
Some elements from HTML5 may not be used in these versions though.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this in your head section:

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: Please use this in your head section
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />